# What are Gecko's Javascript interpreter engine semantics?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer, evaluation

### Edit

In consideration of the [answer response below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689246/what-are-geckos-javascript-interpreter-engine-semantics/5689644#5689644) regarding the
reference [ECMAScript Language Specification - 11.13.2 Compound Assignment](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.13.2)

Considering why these,

```
javascript:
   o="";  o = o + (o+=1)    ; alert(o);
   o="";  o =     (o+=1) + o; alert(o);
```

are NOT the same. There are temporal semantic issues with left to right script evaluation (ref:[ECMA spec. - The addition operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.6)). One consequence is that the `+` operator is not necessarily commutative.

This can also be seen by with:

```
javascript:
   o=1;  o = o + (o+=1)    ; alert(o);
   o=1;  o =     (o+=1) + o; alert(o);
```

or

```
javascript:
   o=" _ ";  o = o + (o+=1)    ; alert(o);
   o=" _ ";  o =     (o+=1) + o; alert(o);
```

The lazy evaluation paradigm, erroneously and inappropriately used by me thereby creating the problem below, is also a bad attribute of my personal modus operandi.

---

### Original Post

The following considerations may already have been addressed, though it seems not. If so, could links to the discussions be provided?

The formal denotational semantics of the Gecko Javascript runtime engine are an enigma.
Empirical testing is exhausting and cannot be exhaustive.

- Is there available an authoritative
  formal specification or official
  reference defining exactly how Gecko
  interprets Javascript?

The reference, [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10), seems inadequate, though credence is provided for the concoction of such scripts like,

```
javascript: alert( function(){return {}}().life=42 )
```

with the consequent meaning of such constructs when binding values.

- Is there a definitive paradigm
  describing the Javascript code
  interpretation for object and
  instance evaluation?

This would clarify the concepts of call by (or rather use by) need, value, reference, inference, name, ... as relevant or not. That, Javascript is a prototyping interpreter, gives implicit meaning to some of the issues below.

What is the expected result of:

```
javascript: o={n:0}; f=function(){o.n+=1; return 10};
   alert([
      o.n,            f(),
      o.n,       o.n+=f(),
      o.n, eval('o.n+=f()'), 
      o.n, eval('o.n+='+f()),
      o.n,
   ].join(",\t"));
```

? Is it easy to predict the results (correctly!)?

The question is a bit rhetorical since it was specifically contrived with `eval`'s to coerce and emphasize the subtle nuances of the interpretation.  Can the evaluation of this script (and the aside below) be resolved with either, the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/) or another document, alluded to earlier?

(As an aside, consider:

```
javascript: ra=[];
   alert([
      ra, ra[ra.length]=" partially defined.",
      ra, ra.push("\n RA is not shown"),
      ra, ra.reverse()[42],
   ].join(",\t\t"));
```

which displays:

```
 RA is not shown, partially defined.,        partially defined.,        
 RA is not shown, partially defined.,       2,      
 RA is not shown, partially defined.,
```

where the partial evaluations of `ra` are NOT analogous to `o.n`'s!

and the following which is less exotic than using o.n:

```
javascript: o=""; f=function(){o+=1; return 0};
   alert([
      o,          f(),
      o,       o+=f(),
      o, eval('o+=f()'), 
      o, eval('o+='+f()),
      o,
   ].join(",\t"));
```

which displays:

```
,   0,  1,  10, 10, 100,    100,    10010,  10010
```

)

Considering the following script:

```
javascript:
   asn="\t\t and so now,\t o.n is "; nl="\n\n";
   o={}; f=function(){o.n+=1; return 10};
   alert(["Using:\n",window.navigator.userAgent,
   nl,"The function f() is:\n ",f,
   nl,"What the!!?!? \t\t\t\t\t\t\t initially \t\t o.n is ",          o.n = 0,
 nl,"Called as a procedure: \t\tf() is ", f(),                   asn, o.n,
nl,"but, instead of 12 \t\to.n+=f() is ", o.n+=f(),              asn, o.n,
     nl,"however eval'd\t\to.n+=f() is ", eval("o.n+="+f()),     asn, o.n,
    "!\n\nIt makes no functional difference if, instead of o.n, o['n'] is used.",
    "\nThe expected o.n evaluation sequence is 0, 1, (+1+10=) 12, (+1+10=) 23.",
    "\n_____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____^^ missing in result",
  ].join(""));
```

The Gecko engine outputs:

```
Using:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3)
        Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3

The function f() is:
 function () {
    o.n += 1;
    return 10;
}

What the!!?!?                                initially       o.n is 0

Called as a procedure:      f() is 10        and so now,     o.n is 1

but, instead of 12      o.n+=f() is 11       and so now,     o.n is 11

however eval'd          o.n+=f() is 22       and so now,     o.n is 22!

It makes no functional difference if, instead of o.n, o['n'] is used.
The expected o.n evaluation sequence is 0, 1, (+1+10=) 12, (+1+10=) 23.
_____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____^^ missing in result
```

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer, but it seems to make perfect sense. `o.n` is evaluated seperately each time, giving you the integer currently stored in `o`'s field `n` - the field is later overwritten, the integer previously stored in it isn't mutate. The second example puts seveal references to the same object into the results array and mutates it in the meanwhile, so when you look at the end result, you look at the same object several times.

Comment: Not sure why you're calling out "Gecko" multiple times (it's actually Mozilla's SpiderMonkey). Why didn't you also test in Chrome and Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has an eager evaluation (call by value) execution model clearly spelled out in the ECMA standard. All of these questions can be resolved by carful reading of the standard. For example, the reason why the result is 11 above and not 12 is clearly spelled out in 11.13.2 of the standard. o.n is evaluated prior to the call to f() not after as specified by step 2.

Comment: Many thanks - got me thinking - see edit preceding the original post.

Comment: All languages that allow side-effects have a similar problem. Some languages, such as C & C++, even go so far as to say the order of evaulation is undefined allowing implementation to vary as to what the result is given. JavaScript cannot, so explicitly specifies the order. In any case, in a side-effecting procedural langauge avoid constructs that make the side-effect visible such as o = o + (o+=1) or, more traditinally, o = o + ++o.

Comment: or even `((o=1)+(++o))` as opposed to `((++o)+(o=1))` !

Comment: Yes, all such things should be avoided in C or C influenced languages. They are standardized in Java, C# and JavaScript, left undefined in C & C++ and are ugly in all of them.